# InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 5 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5).?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, vgg-net

i trained my train set with vgg 16 model, I just loaded 5 different classes images, why I get this error below? i just load 5 classes, I should set dense with 5 class. why is that out of range?

```
# Flatten the output layer to 1 dimension
x = layers.Flatten()(base_model.output)

# Add a fully connected layer with 512 hidden units and ReLU activation
x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)

# Add a dropout rate of 0.5
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

# Add a final sigmoid layer for classification
x = layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(base_model.input, x)
```

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 5 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5).  Label values: 4 3 5 3 3 4 3 4 2 1 1 5 2 5 5 1 1 1 3 1 1 2 1 1 3 5 4 1 5 3 5 1 1 2 2 2 5 2 2 5 2 5 4 5 5 2 3 4 4 3 4 2 5 5 4 3 4 3 2 1 1 2 5 4
```

Comment: How did you labeled 5 classes? Can you share complete code to replicate your issue?  so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67446643/14290681), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64495478/14290681) may answer your question. Thanks!